# How to go about proving the sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, cauchy-sequences

The statement of the question is:

Suppose $f$ maps the open interval $E$ into itself, $0 < b < 1$, $f$ has property $X(b)$ (that property is Lipschitz continuous), and
$x_0 \in E$ Prove that the sequence $\{ x_k\}$ defined recursively by $x_k = f(x_{k−1})$ for $k \geq 1$
converges.

What I have thus far :

Given $x_0 \in E$, we have $ x_n \in E$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

let $n = 0, 1, ..., k-1$

Then we can rewrite the given property $X(b)$ and $f(x_{k-1}) = x_k$ as:

$|x_{ k+1 } -  x_k | =  |f(x_k) - f(x_{ k - 1})| \leq b |x_k - x_{ k - 1}| $

And then by induction

$|x_{k+1} - x_k| \leq b |x_k - x_{ k-1}| \leq ... \leq b ^k |x_1 - x_0|$

Thus,

$ |x_{k+1} - x_k| \leq b^k |x_1 - x_0 | $

Note that given $x_0$, then $x_1 - x_0$ is a constant and  $|b| < 1 $ then $b^k \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$ and thus the entire expression $ b^k | x_1 - x_0 | $ will tend to zero as $k \rightarrow \infty$ and so,

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}|x_{k+1}-x_{k}| \leq 0$$

I want prove what I have is Cauchy but I am not sure what to set my variables? or how to tie it all together...

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer was incorrect.  What that answer proved is:  For every $\epsilon > 0$ and every $n$, there is some $N$ such that for every $k \ge N$, $|x_{k+n} - x_k| < \epsilon$.  But to prove that the sequence is Cauchy, you need to know that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $N$ such that for every $k \ge N$ and every $n$, $|x_{k+n} - x_k| < \epsilon$.  In other words, $N$ cannot depend on $n$.

To fix the proof, note that
\begin{align*}
|x_{k+n} - x_k| &= |(x_{k+1} - x_k) + (x_{k+2} - x_{k+1}) + \cdots + (x_{k+n} - x_{k+n-1})|\\
&\le |x_{k+1} - x_k| + |x_{k+2} - x_{k+1}| + \cdots + |x_{k+n} - x_{k+n-1}|.
\end{align*}
Now fill in your bound for each absolute value of a difference and use the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series.

Comment: Thank you so much! So do I drop the whole argument about the limit going to zero and back start back from $ |x_{k+1} - x_k| \leq b^k |x_1 - x_0 | $ ?

Comment: Yes.  The fact that $\lim_{k \to \infty} |x_{k+1}-x_k| = 0$ is not enough to prove that the sequence is Cauchy.  Start from $|x_{k+1} - x_k| \le b^k |x_1 - x_0|$.  You will also need the fact that $\lim_{k \to \infty} b^k = 0$.